# How to install mesa (python package) for use in python 3

Tags: python, pip, installation, anaconda, mesa-abm

I have installed mesa via:

```
$ pip install mesa
```

but it is automatically installing it into

```
/Users/MyName/Documents/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mesa/~
```

which means that when I try to run it with a Python 3 kernel, it can't find the module and I receive the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mesa'
```

Could someone help me out? I'm assuming the problem is that it is automatically installed into the python 2.7 directory - how can i change this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install packages for Python3 while exists Python2,

try this

```
python3 -m pip install xxx
```

or this

```
sudo apt install pip3 
pip3 install xxx
```

Comment: knew it would be something stupidly simple! Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

You should use `pip3` instead of `pip`:

```
pip3 install mesa
```

If you don't have `pip3` install it using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
```

If it doesn't work you can do it manually using `curl`:

```
curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
python get-pip.py
```

You can also execute it straight from `python3`:

```
python3 -m pip install mesa
```

It is always a good practice to set `pip` command to be equivalent to your `python` command. i.e, if `python` points to `python3`, you better change `pip` to point to `pip3`. Add `alias pip='pip3'` to your `~/.bash_profile` file.